# How can I add more than 3 additional FTP accounts for the same subdomain/subscription in Plesk?

Tags: subdomain, ftp, plesk, accounts

Using the option "Subscriptions > (mysite) > Websites and domains > FTP Access" I can add up to 2 additional FTP accounts (in addition to the first one) which I can use to point to other folders in the same space, so those users don't have access to the whole subdomain, just an specific folder. That's a total of 3 FTP accounts.

But how can I add more than 3 FTP accounts? After adding the third one, the button to add another FTP account disappears and there is only the Remove button to remove an account. If I remove one account of the three, the "Add" button comes back.

So there is a limit of 3 FTP accounts in my Plesk. How can I change this limit?
(I do have root access to the server if necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should switch to Service Provider view interface at Server Managment --> Tools and settings --> Plesk Appearance --> Interface views. Then go to Hosting Services --> Subscriptions, click on the needed subscription, click on Customize link at the top of the page, scroll down Resources tab and make sure there is an Ulimited tick against Additional FTP accounts field or set a number manually.

To set up a ftp account for a subdomain only you would need to set Home directory to `/subdomain.domain.tld` when at Power User view interface at Websites & Domains --> FTP Access --> Edit Additional FTP Account.

Comment: This is just what I needed. Thank you! After changing this setting I get a blue lock icon at the left of the domain in "Subscriptions" instead of the green tick icon I see in the rest of domains/subscriptions. If I hover the mouse cursor over that lock icon I get the message "The subscription is blocked for synchronization. It has been excluded from synchronization of the service plan because the subscription parameters have been customized". What do I do if I want to go back to sync with the plan settings at some point in the future?

Comment: In this case you should edit your service plan instead. Go to Hosting services --> Service Plans , change the ftp limit under Resources tab. Once you alter your service plan all subscribtions that use it will update. If you don't want that then create a new service plan and assign it to that subscription only.

Answer (score 0):

I've found another way to do it from console (needs root or a user with the appropriate permissions). Just type the following in the server console:

```
plesk bin subscription_settings --update mydomain.com -max_subftp_users -1
```

(the -1 argument means unlimited additional FTP accounts)